# Installing Ubuntu SDK in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, ubuntu-sdk

It's possible to install the Ubuntu SDK for Ubuntu 16.04?
I'm following the instructions: http://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/platform/sdk/installing-the-sdk/

and this line it's giving me the following error

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install ubuntu-sdk

W: Error de GPG: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/olav-st/xUbuntu_15.10  Release: Las firmas siguientes no se pudieron verificar porque su clave pública no está disponible: NO_PUBKEY 1BE1E8D7A2B5E9D5
E: El repositorio «http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/olav-st/xUbuntu_15.10  Release» no está firmado.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
```

Any idea why is this error happening?

Comment: You got a NO_PUBKEY error when trying to add a repository that was intended for 15.10 in 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, type in terminal: 
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa && sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade && sudo apt install ubuntu-sdk-ide`

Source: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-sdk-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: Still getting an error
W: Error de GPG: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/olav-st/xUbuntu_15.10  Release: Las firmas siguientes no se pudieron verificar porque su clave pública no está disponible: NO_PUBKEY 1BE1E8D7A2B5E9D5
E: El repositorio «http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/olav-st/xUbuntu_15.10  Release» no está firmado.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.

Comment: Please try to remove the correct Trusted software provider Key and than try to reinstall. Go to:  Software & Updates -> Authentication . And remove the correct one